# Mysql replication, error 13 (permission denied) with slave_load_tmpdir

Tags: mysql, replication

I've setup a virtual machine on Azure with Ubuntu 16.10 and Mysql 5.7 for a database replication Master/Slave from another server.

I followed this article: https://www.opsdash.com/blog/mysql-replication-howto.html

All seems to works correctly, replication works but I've serious problems with the use of DATA LOAD INFILE. If I use this command, the replication doesn't works.

I tried with relative varible "slave_load_tmpdir", creating a new directory '/var/slavetmp' and updating my.cnf with these values, but this is the error in mysql with "SHOW SLAVE STATUS":

> Unable to use slave's temporary directory /var/slavetmp - Can't read dir of '/var/slavetmp/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

Have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please run this  - ls -l /var/slavetmp on Slave? think it not have permissions for mysql user

Comment: This is the result:

`total: 0`

Comment: it my mistake - I ask check permission for /var/slavetemp, so need check ls -l /var, so follow next answer from @Jim Parks

Comment: This is after Jim and yours tips: `drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql  4096 Mar  7 23:06 slavetmp` (I'm replying below to Jim..)

Comment: @RRJ, can you post results of:   `ls -l /`

Comment: Hi @thatsaru , sorry but I've deleted this virtual machine. Now I can't get these informations.. I've resolved moving the folder "/var/slavetmp" in `/var/mysql/slavetmp`. In this directory mysql has all permissions to write/read. Tnx - read here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55258/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-parks-mysql-replication-error-13-permission-denied

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the MySQL user is called "mysql" (check for "user" in my.cnf):

1. chown mysql.mysql -R /var/slavetmp
2. Edit /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld.  Copy the lines for /var/lib/mysql and edit the copied lines to refer to /var/slavetmp
3. Restart AppArmor:  /etc/init.d/apparmor restart
4. Restart the mysql service

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55258/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-parks-mysql-replication-error-13-permission-denied).